# References for syntomic cohomology

Tags: cohomology, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Could anyone point to good readable references for learning about syntomic cohomology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the notes [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~swc/notes/files/DLSTsuji2.pdf), though I must confess I haven't read them completely. It has a nice introduction and explains the context.

Comment: It looks like the address has changed slightly:
http://swc.math.arizona.edu/dls/DLSTsuji2.pdf

Comment: To add to the previous comment (in the case that link stops working too), the text is [T. Tsuji: Crystalline sheaves syntomic cohomology and p-adic polylogarithms](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Tsuji+Crystalline+sheaves+syntomic+cohomology+and+p-adic+polylogarithms).
And here is a link [to the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220130073629/https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/dls/DLSTsuji2.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

I collected my very superficial knowledge only from browsing some articles, so that I can't give good bibl. hints. Perhaps [Besser's new construction of syntomic cohomology for smooth schemes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/K-theory/0298/) or [this article by Fontaine and Messing](https://web.archive.org/web/20060503163127/http://www.ams.org/online_bks/conm67/conm67-ch4.pdf) could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Today new in the arXiv: ["Cohomologie syntomique: liens avec les cohomologies étale et rigide"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4436).

Edit: Jan Nekovář announces an appendix to [this](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ejan.nekovar/pu/syn.pdf) article on "foundational aspects of syntomic topology and cohomology" (perhaps obtainable on request?) and mentions descriptions [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/n70871u018675352/) and [here](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-98-09514-X).

Edit: It shows to be useful to look (for the keywords in various languages) for exposés of talks in the late 1980's explaining themes around Fontaine–Messing's article.

Comment: The link to the article at `springerlink.com` is broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible…

Answer (score 2):

Here is a diploma thesis on syntomic cohomology: https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~venjakob/diplom/kuemmerer.pdf